# Symfony2 - How to use @Entity annotations in Controllers?

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony's manual on ParamConverter has this example:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{post_id}")
 * @Entity("post", expr="repository.find(post_id)")
 */
public function showAction(Post $post)
{
}
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression

But using @Entity annotation gives me this error.

```
The annotation "@Entity" in method AppBundle\Controller\CurrencyController::currencyAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

Obviously, I need to use a namespace, but which one? Please help.

Comment: You need to do what error message says - import Entity. You forgot to add a "use" statement on the top of the script.

Comment: Right, but which one exactly? This was the question. SensioFrameworkExtraBundle does not have @Entity annotation (Not in Symfony2 at least), but the manual suggests to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The `Entity` annotation only exist on master (or futur v4).
[Source file here](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/Entity.php)

But as you can see, this is only a shortcut to @ParamConverter annotation with `expr` option, so you have to use this one until next release.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [`ParameterConverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) so this syntax is just wrong.

Use this instead

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{post_id}")
 * @ParamConverter("post_id", class="VendorBundle:Post")
 */
public function showAction(Post $post)
{
}
```

`VendorBundle:Post` should be replaced with whatever your Vendor is (if any) and Bundle is.

Answer (score 1):

Using annotation @ParamConverter with option repository_method is deprecated

```
The repository_method option of @ParamConverter is deprecated and will be removed in 6.0. Use the expr option or @Entity.
```

Thus it's better to use [@Entity (documentation)](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression)

You have to add the namespace :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;
```